# How to restart ngnix server on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, nginx

I recent buy a VPS on DigitalOcean and installed CentOS and follow the tutorial to install Ngnix Server, then I follow the [tutorial to create a Virtual Host](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-virtual-hosts-server-blocks-on-centos-6?utm_source=Customerio&utm_medium=Email_Internal&utm_campaign=Email_CentOSDistroNginxWelcome), but when I put this command to restart:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

Console output an error:

```
sudo: /etc/init.d/nginx: command not found
```

I already search on Google and here for how to solve, but I didn't found solutions.

Comment: Welcome to Unix&Linux @Amanda. Please consider voting for correct replies and marking one of them as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recommend way is as follows. This should work with any Linux distributions or Unix like operating systems:

```
$ nginx -s reload
```

OR

```
$ /path/to/full/nginx -s reload
```

If nginx compiled and installed from source code

```
$ /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -s reload
```